# PySpark, save unique letters in strings of a column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using PySpark, and I want a simple way of doing the next process without it being overcomplicated.

Suppose I have a table that looks like this:

| ID | Letters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a,b,c,d |
| 2 | b,d,b |
| 3 | c,y,u |

I want to get the unique letters in this dataframe from the column "Letters", this would be:
List = [a,b,c,d,y,u].

I tried using the in operator, I don't really know how to iterate through each register, but I don't wanna make a mess because the original plan is for a big dataset.

Comment: Note that if your letters are in an RDD such as `data = sc.parallelize(['abcd','bdb','cyu'])`, then you can just do `letters = data.reduce(lambda x,y: set(x).union(y))`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

data1 = [
    [1, "a,b,c,d"],
    [2, "b,d,b"],
    [3, "c,y,u"],
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data1).toDF("ID", "Letters")

dfWithDistinctValues = df.select(
    F.array_distinct(
        F.flatten(F.collect_set(F.array_distinct(F.split(df.Letters, ","))))
    ).alias("unique_letters")
)

defaultValues = [
    data[0] for data in dfWithDistinctValues.select("unique_letters").collect()
]

print(defaultValues)
```

What is happening here:

1. First i am splitting string by "," with F.split and droping duplicates at row level with F.array_distinct
2. I am using collect_set to get all distinct arrays into one row which is array of arrays at this stage and it looks like this:

   [[b, d], [a, b, c, d], [c, y, u]]
3. Then i am using flatten to get all values as separate strings:

   [b, d, a, b, c, d, c, y, u]
4. There are still some duplicates which are removed by array_distinct so at the end the output looks like this:

   [b, d, a, c, y, u]

If you need also counts you may use explode as Koedit mentioned, you may change part of his code to something like this:

```
# Unique letters with counts
uniqueLettersDf = (
    df.select(explode(array_distinct("Letters")).alias("Letter"))
    .groupBy("Letter")
    .count()
    .show()
)
```

Now you will get something like this:

```
+------+-----+
|Letter|count|
+------+-----+
|     d|    2|
|     c|    2|
|     b|    2|
|     a|    1|
|     y|    1|
|     u|    1|
+------+-----+
```

Comment: This approach is amazing! I didn't know there was a function "array_distinct", I'm new to PySpark. Will this method also work if for example I wanna make a new dataframe counting how many times the letters I found appear?, with the same example:

Edit: Cannot format table on stackoverflow.
The idea is making a new dataframe with two columns "letters" and "count", how many times the letter was found on that specific column.

Comment: If you want to get also counts i think it will be better to use what Koedit (i upvoted it) mentioned in his answer but instead of distinct use normal group by and get count, i edited my asnwer, you may take a look

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how large your dataset and your arrays are (if they are very large, this might not be the route you want to take), you can use the `explode` function to easily get what you want:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (1, ["a", "b", "c", "d"]),
        (2, ["b", "d", "b"]),
        (3, ["c", "y", "u"])
    ],
    ["ID", "Letters"]
)

# Creating a dataframe with 1 column, "letters", with distinct values per row
uniqueLettersDf = df.select(explode("Letters").alias("letters")).distinct()

# Using list comprehension and the .collect() method to turn our dataframe into a Python list
output = [row['letters'] for row in uniqueLettersDf.collect()]

output
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'y', 'u']
```

**EDIT**: To make it a bit safer, we can use `array_distinct` before using `explode`: this will limit the amount of rows that will get made by removing the doubles before exploding.

The code would be identical, except for these lines:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, array_distinct
...
uniqueLettersDf = df.select(explode(array_distinct("Letters")).alias("letters")).distinct()
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, sorry but how you know when to consider which approach for big datasets?

Comment: This is dependent on what your cluster looks like: nr of executors, memory size of executors, ... and also on how large your data and what they contain. There is no "magic formula", that will need to be considered on a case by case basis. But in this case, since you only have the `ID` and the `Letters` column, using `explode` won't really make the data much bigger. To make it a bit safer, you could use the `array_distinct` function that M_S used before exploding.

Comment: I upvoted and added part of your answer to my answer as OP mentioned that he needs also counts. I think that in such case its better to just use explode + group by